# Persisting a bearer token

Tags: c#, security, encryption

I have a C# CLI application which needs to be executed many times on Windows (with the same domain user), potentially on multiple servers, within the space of a few minutes during regular nightly processing. This application requires a bearer token (which is valid for one hour) from an authentication server in order to access a service on the local network. I have implemented logic to request a bearer token using a Http request.

There is a problem, in that the DNS has an anti-DDoS measure in place which means that during the few minute window when this application is executed many times, many of the requests fail, and so the application fails. The obvious solution to this is to somehow persist a single token between calls and use that if it is available. Otherwise make a new http request.

Is there a secure way to store such a token on a network share/service in such a way that it would be accessible only to this application and/or calling user? I wouldn't want to leave a plaintext bearer token in a file as this would be a security risk to the system.

I found some .NET Core APIs which make it possible to encrypt data/files apparently using some information about the current user, which means only that user can decrypt it. However, it doesn't restrict access per application, so somebody could drop their own application in our task framework which calls the same API and decrypt the token if they wanted. Doesn't seem so secure.

Comment: I think you are solving two different problems here - one, authenticating as the user, and two, restricting the obtained token only to your application. I don't think the second restriction possible If you are assuming that your application data/secrets can be read by other applications on behalf of the same user. In order to ensure only your application can perform the related operation, you will need some secret on the application.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use [`ProtectedData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class to encrypt ([`Protect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.protect?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)) and decrypt ([`UnProtect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.unprotect?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)) data.

You can use [`DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), in this way, only the user that the application is running under can decrypt.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented this, but it appears there is a limitation in that it can only be decrypted on the same machine. Is there a way to get around that? Or an alternative which doesn't have that limitation?